# How do I install both D2007 and D2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, components, delphi-2007

From what I have gathered, one can have both editions of Delphi installed. My concern is that default paths, etc, may get confused especially when installing 3rd party components.

The reason why I want to do this is I have some 3rd party components which have not been updated. Although I have the source files, I'm not knowledgeable enough to update them. I have tried compiling it for D2010 and received so many errors that it would be easier to install and use it in D2007.

I'm running Windows 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not install them in two different VM's?

Comment: Actually, that is what I did in the end. I had to reinstall my OS, and decided to install D2010 on the main OS and D6 in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parallel installation of Delphi itself is no problem.

Regarding 3rd party components: Some of them (like JEDI) are able to recognize different installed Delphi versions and so you have no problem too. 
For all the other components I recommend to install them into different directories (and therefore use different Delphi library paths).

But if you have no Delphi 2009+ (Unicode) version of your library/component, you have to look for an updated version or update it yourself (, which may be complicated; there are many threads here on SO).

Comment: In short, if you avoid the horrible problem of recompiling a package named MyPackage so that two "MyPackage.bpl" files are in your path, you will be fine. This is the reason for the usual practice of having numbered suffixes on your package names. 14 = delphi 2010, 12= delphi 2007,  7 = delphi 7, etc.

Comment: Actually, I got it wrong when I posted the original question (blame it on old age).

It wasn't D2007, but Delphi 6. I've just installed D6 and that went without any problems. From what I could gather, the paths, etc, are different to those of D2010.

I've forgotten how quickly D6 starts compared to later versions, but then I'm sure when I first installed it on my old computer that I thought it was slow!

Comment: I can slow Delphi 6 down for you. Just install about 100 component packages. :-)